# Not Performing Any action On Button Click : Android

Tags: android

I need a button in android button.I need to show that when button was click it show the character 1 in the TextView field textView. 
So here is my java code.

```
package com.example.kartikeya;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void buttonOnClick(){
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView.setText(textView.getText() + "" + 1);
        }
    });
}
```

This is my activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Button
    android:text="@string/button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:textColor="#0A0A0A"
    android:textSize="25sp"

    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
    android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"

    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/click1"
    android:contextClickable="true" />

<Button
```

Answer (score 4):

You forget to call your method. `buttonOnClick();`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buttonOnClick();
}
```

Comment: +1, though I would move the code of the method in the `onCreate()` method, or call it something like `setupButton()` here.

Comment: @BenjaminScharbau agreed, or change the name as `initButton();`

Answer (score 3):

Try this way

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        textView.setText(textView.getText() + "" + 1);
    }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the text view in your activity.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

you never called this fuction... buttonOnClick()

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10636352)

Comment: @DamianKozlak Why not? Have you seen the other answers?

Comment: @chichiangho During the review I see only question and your answer. I don't see other people's answers. Your answer looked pretty simple, without more explanation where he should do it, so someone flagged it as low quality answer. Also now I see that, you repeated Berkay's answer.

Comment: @DamianKozlak when I comment,I didn't see the other answers.and my answer is short,that's my fault.I think this is a simple mistake caused by carelessness

Answer (score 0):

In MainActivity write following code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clickBtn);
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          textView.setText(textView.getText() + "" + 1);
        }
    });
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/clickBtn"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text = "click me"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```